# Can't add Keyboard Eventlistener actionscript

Tags: events, actionscript, listener

I am just starting to learn actionscript, and to help get used to the syntax, I am challenging myself to make a simple game where you are a circle that shoots falling blocks.

For some reason every time I try to add a keyboard event listener the game doesn't run.

Here is my player file.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
public class Player extends Sprite
{
    //Variables
    private var playerRadius:Number = 50;
    private var playerX:Number = 5;
    private var playerY:Number = 5;
    private var speed:Number = 0;
    private var xvel:Number = 0;

    public function Player()
    {
        init(); 
        //Drawing
        drawPlayer();
        //Event Listeners
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updatePlayer);
                    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, controlPlayer);  
    }
    //Update
    public function updatePlayer(event:Event):void{
        this.x ++;
    }
    //Draw
    private function drawPlayer():void{
        graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        graphics.drawCircle(10,10,50);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
    //Control
    public function controlPlayer(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
            speed = 5;
        }
    }

}
}
```

With this code I just get a white screen, but if I comment out

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, controlPlayer);
```

it works, but I don't have control of the player.

I'd appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code I was able to figure out your issue which ultimately turned out to be a couple problems with your code.  I'm surprised you were not seeing the following error in the Flash 'Output' Panel when you tested the application:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Player()
at Player_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

1. The first issue is that when you create an object of the type `Player`, it isn't yet added to the Stage, so it does not yet have access to the `stage` object.
2. Once the player object is added to the Stage, only then will you be able to add the listener for keyboard events to the stage; however, for this to happen, your `Player` class needs to be made aware of the fact that an instance of it was added to the stage so that it knows exactly when it should register the keyboard event listener.

Here is an updated version of your code that should resolve these issues:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Player extends Sprite
    {
        //Variables
        private var playerRadius:Number = 50;
        private var playerX:Number = 5;
        private var playerY:Number = 5;
        private var speed:Number = 0;
        private var xvel:Number = 0;

        public function Player()
        {
            init(); 

            //Drawing
            drawPlayer();

            //Event Listeners
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updatePlayer);
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initKeyboardListener);
        }

        public function initKeyboardListener(event:Event) {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, controlPlayer);
        }

        //Update
        public function updatePlayer(event:Event):void{
            this.x++;
        }

        //Draw
        private function drawPlayer():void{
            graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            graphics.drawCircle(10,10,50);
            graphics.endFill();
        }

        //Control
        public function controlPlayer(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
                this.speed = 5;
            }
        }

    } // end class

} // end package
```

For all of this to work, don't forget to add the player object to the stage. I can only assume you have done this since you haven't shared any code showing where you use the `Player` class, but here is an example of what I am referring to:

```
import Player;

var player:Player = new Player();
stage.addChild(player);
```

Also, the keyboard listener simply alters the `speed` variable; however the speed variable hasn't been implemented anywhere else in your code, so you won't see the difference in the GUI until this is fixed.  I verified that all the listeners were working as they should using trace statements.

Comment: Glad it helped you out.  If it was the answer you were looking for, please mark the answer as accepted.  Cheers.